# Google Vertex AI image AutoML classification when an important image feature is text inside the image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'd like to do **image classification**. In my dataset, despite the fact that images features is a strong component for this classification (colors, shapes, etc), **some categories** of images will be **hard to distinguish without interpreting the text inside the image**.

I don't think VertexAI/AutoML will use pre-trained models in order to facilitate classification if in some case the only difference is the text. I know Google Vision/OCR is capable of doing such extraction. But **is there a way to do image classification (VertexAI/AutoML) using Google Cloud Vision extraction as an additional image feature**?

Currently my project uses 3 models (no google cloud):

- *model 1*: classify an image using images features
- *model 2*: classify an image, only using OCR + regex (same categories)
- *model 3*: combine both models and decide when to use model 1 or model 2

I'd like to switch to Vertex AI the following will improve my project quality for the following:

- AutoML classification seems very good for *model 1*
- I need to use a tool to manage my datasets (Vertex AI managed dataset)
- Vertex AI has interesting pipeline training features

If it is confirmed that AutoML won't perform well if some images categories only differs in the text, I would recreate a similar 3-tier models using Vertex AI custom training scripts. I can easily create *model 1* with VertexAI/AutoML. However I have no idea if:

- I can create *model 2* with a vertex ai custom training script using google cloud vision/ocr to do image classification
- I can create *model 3* that would use *models 1* and *2* created by vertex ai.

Could you give me recommendations on how to achieve that using Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, I recommend you the following:

**1. model 2:**

- Keep your images in a `GCS`.
- Use the [Detect text in images  |  Cloud Vision API](http://cloud/vision/docs/ocr)  to generate your dataset (text) `{"gcs":"gs://path_to_image/image_1","text":["text1"...]}`.
- Use AutoML on this text dataset processed by vision api **or** just use a regexp on this data **or** insert into a bigquery dataset and query on it, and so on...

**1. model 3:**

- I would follow a similar approach, processing the images using the cloud vision API and generating a text dataset, but this time, the images that dont have any text on it, will generate a dataset with the `"text"` field empty `{"gcs":"gs://path_to_image/image_2","text":[]}`. Your own script can exclude the data with text and generate a dataset for the model 2, and a dataset for the model 1.

I see that your models 2 and 3 are not strictly classifications. Model 2 is a ocr problem, and them you process the output data. The model 3 is basically process your data and separate the proper datasets.

I hope this insight may help you.

Comment: ewertonvsilva: Hi, thanks for your answer. Wiktor: it anwsers it partly. Concerning point 1 on model 2: I don't recognize the format you're mentioning. I understand it should be a text dataset format, I'm expecting to have this dataset import format: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-text#single-label-classification . Same for model 3. I'm a newbie on GC. I agree model 2 could be a non-ML problem (if using regex). Model 3 should be ML and compute the weights that determine when to use model 1 OR 2. Also model 2 and 3 should be used to process new data after training.

Comment: Hi Kain! What I mean is, every image dataset **is** a text dataset, because you have to create a dataset with the path for your images. The purposed idea is to create this dataset using the vision api. As you can check in [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-image), a image dataset is a regular text dataset with the `"imageGcsUri": "gs://bucket/filename.ext"` field pointing to the image in place of a text itself.